# Split outlet pipe

Tags: shower, pipe, plumbing-fixture, old-pipes

In a prefabricated shower stall, the outlet pipe is split.

You can see the slit-like opening in this picture:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can guess, this makes the shower unusable, as the water will leak in a strong stream through this hole.

I tried to remove the entire metallic piece, but I was unable to. I don't dare rotate it too hard, as I fear I will break it. I don't know how to remove it entirely.

Any suggestion as to how I could:

1. seal this slit-like opening?
2. remove this metal head to work on it more easily?

For context, here is the shower:

[image]

Comment: Since this is a prefab unit it could be there are non-standard proprietary joints, e.g., it could be this joint is crimped and not separable. (If that proves to be the case, a last resort possible repair might be inserting tubing inside the fitting and gluing with JB Weld.) To understand possible type of fitting I recall that a relative of mine in Germany has a shower hose fitting that looks like that so maybe look in European sources.

Comment: Usually the threads on shower arms are parallel threads and the part that mates has a soft rubber "washer" seal. So these only need to be tightened enough to slightly compress the seal (no thread sealer is required). As the seal hardens with age this joint may begin to leak for whiich the normal remedy is to tighten it, but this can lead to over-tightening which would stress the joint.

Comment: Can you get us a pic of the crack from a slightly lower angle (i.e. below the fitting)?

Comment: @Huesmann I added a few pictures, thanks

Comment: @JimStewart thanks, I tried that but unfortunately that did not work. There is indeed a rubber washer seal, but when I tighten it, there is still a leak alongside the slit-like hole.

Comment: Any mfgr designation on this unit? What would be a good generic descriptor for this type of unit?

Comment: Doing a Google search led to numerous models of this sort of wall elbow showing them screwing on with 1/2" NPT. So maybe a lot of CCW torque would free it. The joint would require thread sealer.

Comment: The new pics seem to indicate that the threaded "spout" is actually plastic.  Is that so, @DevShark?

Comment: @Huesmann that is correct, the thread is plastic

Comment: @JimStewart unfortunately, I cannot find any reference to the manufacturer on the shower

Comment: @JimStewart Do you mean I should try to unscrew the spout only, or the whole metallic round head? Can you share one of the links you saw? Thanks!

Comment: Niagara Comfort Shower GP2005H, possibly Russian in origin?

Comment: @Huesmann Ah possibly. I struggle to make sense of the online results. From what I see, I think the GP2500H might refer only to the electronic radio system, rather than the whole shower enclosure.

Comment: I Googled "wall elbow for hand held shower". One I looked at screwed on with 1/2" female NPT mating with 1/2" male NPT. I will send some links. But I was hasty when I generalized that all connect that way. Probably there are different connection types. It might destroy the connection to turn CCW with more and more force.

Comment: I meant unscrew the whole thing, not just the cracked pipe. https://www.amazon.com/Delta-Faucet-50560-BL-Elbow-Shower/dp/B06XHSPTXP/ref=pd_ci_mcx_pspc_dp_d_2_t_2?pd_rd_w=NpTK3&content-id=amzn1.sym.568f3b6b-5aad-4bfd-98ee-d827f03151e4&pf_rd_p=568f3b6b-5aad-4bfd-98ee-d827f03151e4&pf_rd_r=XY4MB4V37TYR6EEC0C58&pd_rd_wg=2ZSNC&pd_rd_r=bdaeb10b-29d7-4487-9847-ee2df783887e&pd_rd_i=B06XHSPTXP&th=1

Comment: This one shows how it is connected https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BNH2ZX2Q/ref=sspa_dk_detail_1?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B0BNH2ZX2Q&pd_rd_w=LZPI9&content-id=amzn1.sym.0d1092dc-81bb-493f-8769-d5c802257e94&pf_rd_p=0d1092dc-81bb-493f-8769-d5c802257e94&pf_rd_r=XY4MB4V37TYR6EEC0C58&pd_rd_wg=2ZSNC&pd_rd_r=bdaeb10b-29d7-4487-9847-ee2df783887e&s=hi&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9kZXRhaWwy

Comment: @JimStewart thanks for that. I will give it a shot.